# This is my impression of askubuntu

Tags: discussion, support

My last Q was about odd behaviour during intramfs.

The Q is [GRUB starts but init cant read any media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363252/)

I find the comments asking for clarification unreasonable.

initramfs doesn't change between 20.04.x does it? initramfs doesn't change for server vs desktop does it?

And of course, I get a downvote for my actual solution.   That's just ...

What hurts the most, besides the misrepresentations, is probably
"something that someone who has been a member here for 10 years should know already, by heart."

I deliberately ranted on my Win experience, I thought that would fly here. The support tag is obviously wrong. Sorry for this rant. I'm just frustrated.

Comment: Yeah, rants aren't really welcome in the main site.

Comment: I have never understood why anyone would downvote someone who is looking for information on installing Ubuntu. It is almost like they are working for Apple. Try 7Zip for accessing archive files. https://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: The comment about what you should know is most impolite, but I must admit that I was not able to understand your question or solution. The material about searching for iso writing software seems an unnecessary distraction. If I knew what you wanted to say I would edit to make it clearer myself, but I don't understand what point you've reached in your process (in the question) and the answer refers to things that couldn't have been guessed at based on the information in the question (also it doesn't seem like a solution - what action fixed the problem?)

Comment: I agree that it's not very clear what you are asking in your question. Are you trying to make bootable installation media?  Are you trying to install Ubuntu?  Are you trying to install Ubuntu to a flash drive? Are you trying to create LiveCD media with persistence?  The question is more of a "stream of consciousness" narrative about your frustrations without really identifying what you want. There also aren't many actionable details explaining what exact steps you've taken or details about the actual problems you face. Consider rewriting the question to make sure it's clear and unambiguous.

Comment: The OP seems to be doing things correctly to UEFI boot an ISO's contents that has been extracted to a FAT32 partition on the Windows disk. The problem seems to be with the RAID setup on the disk. I am not qualified to help with RAID. Sounds like an **oldfred** question to me.

Comment: The big problem I see for Ask Ubuntu and Canonical is that most people would not bother to rant, they would just go and download an ISO of MX Linux, Manjaro or Mint and not bother with the rude behavior here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmmm. To me, this looks like two well-meaning people **unintentionally** pushing each other's buttons.

We see each other only through text. Text is a poor conveyance of emotional detail (humans rely on visual and audio cues much more). We don't know if somebody was preoccupied by a bad day at work, or has a 3-day toothache, or is worrying about a sick loved one, or is merely young, or is suffering some other frustration.

From the Ubuntu Code of Conduct:

> Be respectful
>
> Disagreement is no excuse for poor manners. We work together to resolve conflict, assume good intentions and do our best to act in an empathic fashion. We don’t allow frustration to turn into a personal attack. A community where people feel uncomfortable or threatened is not a productive one.

Each of us can go back and edit our own words that carry unintended meaning to be more clear. Or to delete (unintentionally) hurtful comments entirely.

Each of us can make an effort forgive the rudeness of others, especially if unintended; to let it go.

Comment: Each of us can make an effort forgive the rudeness of others, especially if unintended; to let it go.

I appreciate that 535733.

Comment: “or is merely young” young users can be nice.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica yes, obviously.